# Side Step SQL Data Type Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am querying a SQL view but I keep getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Rejected' to data type int.

The query I'm using is as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [event]
FROM V_S_EVENT_TIMESERIES_AP
```

There is no value called "Rejected" in `event` column so I have the following questions:

1. Where is this value coming from?
2. Why is it trying to convert it to INT?
3. How can I sidestep the conversion to avoid the error?

I very much appreciate your help. Thanks a lot in advance.

**[EDIT]:**

The `DDL`:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_S_EVENT_TIMESERIES_AP] 
AS
    SELECT  
        [contactID], [date], [accntID],
        [event], [hasEmail_FLG],
        [CUST_STAT_CD], [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
        [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG], [ACTIVE_FLG],
        [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
        [MAIN_PHONE_NUM], [JOB_ROLE], [JOB_FUNCTION],
        [hasPhone_FLG],
        [workPhoneSuperScore], [QCApproved],
        [HQL_ID], [RESP_TYPE_CD], [STATUS_CD], [OptyID],
        [Disposition], [SubDisposition], [AETimezone]
    FROM
        ((SELECT 
              S_CONTACT.ROW_ID AS [contactID], S_CONTACT.CREATED AS [date],
              'ContactCreation' AS [event],
              CASE
                 WHEN S_CONTACT.EMAIL_ADDR IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
              END AS [hasEmail_FLG],
              S_CONTACT.CUST_STAT_CD, S_CONTACT.SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG, 
              S_CONTACT.SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG, 
              S_CONTACT.SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG,S_CONTACT.ACTIVE_FLG,
              S_CONTACT2.ACCOUNT_ID AS [accntID], S_CONTACT2.WORK_PHONE_NUM,
              S_CONTACT2.MAIN_PHONE_NUM, S_CONTACT2.JOB_ROLE,
              S_CONTACT2.JOB_FUNCTION,
              CASE
                 WHEN S_CONTACT2.MAIN_PHONE_NUM IS NOT NULL OR 
                      S_CONTACT2.WORK_PHONE_NUM IS NOT NULL 
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
              END AS [hasPhone_FLG],
              CASE
                 WHEN S_CONTACT2.WORK_PHONE_NUM IS NOT NULL AND 
                      S_CONTACT2.WORK_PHONE_NUM != S_CONTACT2.MAIN_PHONE_NUM 
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
              END AS [workPhoneSuperScore], 
              NULL AS [QCApproved], NULL AS [HQL_ID],
              NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD], NULL AS [OptyID],
              NULL AS [Disposition], NULL AS [SubDisposition],
              NULL AS [AETimezone]
          FROM 
              Reporting.dbo.S_CONTACT
          LEFT JOIN 
              AnalyticsDB.dbo.V_S_CONTACT_full AS [S_CONTACT2] ON S_CONTACT.ROW_ID = S_CONTACT2.CONTACT_ID)

          UNION

          (SELECT 
               S_CONTACT2.CONTACT_ID AS [contactID],
               S_CONTACT2.X_LINKEDIN_VERIFIED_DATE AS [date],
               'LinkedInVerification' AS [event],
               NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
               NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], 
               NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
               NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG], NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
               S_CONTACT2.ACCOUNT_ID AS [accntID], NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
               NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM], NULL AS [JOB_ROLE], NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
               NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
               NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], NULL AS [QCApproved],
               NULL AS [HQL_ID], NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], 
               NULL AS [STATUS_CD], NULL AS [OptyID],
               NULL AS [Disposition], NULL AS [SubDisposition],
               NULL AS [AETimezone]
           FROM 
               AnalyticsDB.dbo.V_S_CONTACT_full AS [S_CONTACT2]
           WHERE 
               S_CONTACT2.X_LINKEDIN_VERIFIED_DATE IS NOT NULL)
          UNION
          (SELECT 
               S_CONTACT2.CONTACT_ID AS [contactID],
               S_CONTACT2.X_MRP_VERIFIED_DATE AS [date],
               'MRPVerification' AS [event],
               NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG], NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD], 
               NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
               NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG], NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
               S_CONTACT2.ACCOUNT_ID AS [accntID],
               NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM], NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],
               NULL AS[JOB_ROLE], NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
               NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG], NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore],
               NULL AS [QCApproved], NULL AS [HQL_ID],
               NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD],
               NULL AS [OptyID], NULL AS [Disposition],
               NULL AS [SubDisposition], NULL AS [AETimezone]
           FROM 
               AnalyticsDB.dbo.V_S_CONTACT_full AS [S_CONTACT2]
           WHERE 
               S_CONTACT2.X_MRP_VERIFIED_DATE IS NOT NULL)
          UNION
          (SELECT 
               S_CONTACT3.ROW_ID AS [contactID],S_CONTACT3.X_MRP_EMAIL_VERIFIED_DATE AS [date], 
                                'MRPEmailVerification' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    S_CONTACT2.ACCOUNT_ID AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore],NULL AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD],NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM Reporting.dbo.S_CONTACT_X AS [S_CONTACT3]
                            LEFT JOIN AnalyticsDB.dbo.V_S_CONTACT_full AS [S_CONTACT2]
                                  ON S_CONTACT3.ROW_ID =S_CONTACT2.CONTACT_ID
                            WHERE S_CONTACT3.X_MRP_EMAIL_VERIFIED_DATE IS NOT NULL)
                        UNION
                            (SELECT S_CONTACT3.ROW_ID AS [contactID],S_CONTACT3.X_DIRECT_DIAL_VERIFIED_DATE AS [date], 
                                'DirectDialVerification' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    S_CONTACT2.ACCOUNT_ID AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore],NULL AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD],NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM Reporting.dbo.S_CONTACT_X AS [S_CONTACT3]
                            LEFT JOIN AnalyticsDB.dbo.V_S_CONTACT_full AS [S_CONTACT2]
                                  ON S_CONTACT3.ROW_ID =S_CONTACT2.CONTACT_ID
                            WHERE S_CONTACT3.X_DIRECT_DIAL_VERIFIED_DATE IS NOT NULL)
                        UNION
                            (SELECT S_CONTACT3.ROW_ID AS [contactID],S_CONTACT3.X_JOB_TITLE_VERIFIED_DATE AS [date], 
                                'JobVerification' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    S_CONTACT2.ACCOUNT_ID AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore],NULL AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD],NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM Reporting.dbo.S_CONTACT_X AS [S_CONTACT3]
                            LEFT JOIN AnalyticsDB.dbo.V_S_CONTACT_full AS [S_CONTACT2]
                                  ON S_CONTACT3.ROW_ID =S_CONTACT2.CONTACT_ID
                            WHERE S_CONTACT3.X_JOB_TITLE_VERIFIED_DATE IS NOT NULL)
                        UNION
                            (SELECT S_CONTACT4.CONTACT_ID AS [contactID],S_CONTACT4.X_MEETING_BOOKED_DT AS [date], 
                                'MeetingBooked' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    S_CONTACT4.ACCOUNT_ID AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore],NULL AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD],NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM AnalyticsDB.dbo.V_S_CONTACT AS [S_CONTACT4]
                            WHERE S_CONTACT4.X_MEETING_BOOKED_DT IS NOT NULL)
                        UNION
                            (SELECT V_S_OPPORTUNITIES.ContactID AS [contactID],V_S_OPPORTUNITIES.Meeting_Date AS [date], 
                                'MeetingBooked' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    V_S_OPPORTUNITIES.Account_ID AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], V_S_OPPORTUNITIES.QC_APPROVED AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD],NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM [AnalyticsDB].[dbo].[V_S_OPPORTUNITIES]
                            WHERE V_S_OPPORTUNITIES.Meeting_Date IS NOT NULL                           
                            )
                        UNION
                            (SELECT COMM.PR_CON_ID AS [contactID],HQL.CREATED AS [date], 
                                'HQL' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    COMM.ACCNT_ID AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], 
                                    HQL.ROW_ID AS [HQL_ID],COMM.X_MRP_HQL_QC_STAT AS [QCApproved],
                                    COMM.RESP_TYPE_CD, COMM.STATUS_CD,NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM SiebProd.dbo.CX_MRP_HQL_RESP AS [HQL]            
                            LEFT JOIN Reporting.dbo.S_COMMUNICATION AS [COMM] 
                                ON COMM.ROW_ID = HQL.PAR_ROW_ID
                                WHERE HQL.CREATED IS NOT NULL)
                        UNION 
                            (SELECT NULL AS [contactID],V_Opty_Incl_QcPendRw_lgTopic.CREATED AS [date], 
                                'Opportunity' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    V_Opty_Incl_QcPendRw_lgTopic.Acct_ID AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], 
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],NULL AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD], V_Opty_Incl_QcPendRw_lgTopic.ROW_ID AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM [AnalyticsDB].[dbo].[V_Opty_Incl_QcPendRw_lgTopic]
                            WHERE V_Opty_Incl_QcPendRw_lgTopic.CREATED IS NOT NULL) 
                        UNION 
                            (SELECT V_NGIS_OPTY.CONTACT_ID AS [contactID],V_NGIS_OPTY.DATE AS [date], 
                                'Opportunity' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    V_NGIS_OPTY.ACCOUNT_ID AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], 
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],NULL AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD], V_NGIS_OPTY.OPTY_ID AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM [AnalyticsDB].[dbo].[V_NGIS_OPTY]
                            WHERE V_NGIS_OPTY.DATE IS NOT NULL) 
                        UNION 
                            (SELECT V_S_OPPORTUNITIES.ContactID AS [contactID],V_S_OPPORTUNITIES.OPTY_CREATED AS [date], 
                                'Opportunity' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    V_S_OPPORTUNITIES.Account_ID AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], 
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],NULL AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD], V_S_OPPORTUNITIES.OPTY_ID AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM [AnalyticsDB].[dbo].[V_S_OPPORTUNITIES]
                            WHERE V_S_OPPORTUNITIES.OPTY_CREATED IS NOT NULL) 
                          UNION
                            (SELECT V_S_LEAD_FUTURES.[Contact ID] [contactID],V_S_LEAD_FUTURES.[Response Date] AS [date], 
                                'LeadFuture' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    V_S_LEAD_FUTURES.[Account ID] AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], 
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],NULL AS [QCApproved],
                                    V_S_LEAD_FUTURES.[Response Type] AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], V_S_LEAD_FUTURES.[Response Status] AS [STATUS_CD], NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM [AnalyticsDB].[dbo].[V_S_LEAD_FUTURES]
                            WHERE V_S_LEAD_FUTURES.[Response Date] IS NOT NULL) 
                        UNION
                            (SELECT DISTINCT act.PR_CON_ID AS [contactID],act.TODO_PLAN_START_DT AS [date], 
                                'NGISCall' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    CON.ACCOUNT_ID AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], 
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],NULL AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD],
                                    NULL AS [STATUS_CD], NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    act.COMMENTS AS [Disposition],act.X_CALL_DISPOSITION AS [SubDisposition],
                                    Timezone.NAME AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM SiebProd.DBO.S_EVT_ACT AS [Act]
                        INNER JOIN SiebProd.dbo.S_CONTACT AS [Contact] 
                                ON Contact.ROW_ID=Act.CREATED_BY
                        INNER JOIN AnalyticsDB.dbo.V_S_CONTACT_w_MOBILE_NUM AS [con] 
                                ON con.CONTACT_ID = act.PR_CON_ID
                        INNER JOIN SiebProd.dbo.S_TIMEZONE AS [Timezone] 
                                ON Timezone.ROW_ID=Contact.TIMEZONE_ID
                        WHERE 
                            Act.TODO_CD='Call Disposition' AND Act.COMMENTS IS NOT NULL AND Act.REF_NUM IS NOT NULL AND Act.X_CALL_DISPOSITION IS NOT NULL 
                            AND Act.X_DISPOSITION_FLG='Y' AND act.PR_CON_ID IS NOT NULL)
                        UNION
                            (SELECT V_S_DMLEAD.[Contact ID] [contactID],
                              CASE
                                WHEN V_S_DMLEAD.[Last Login] > V_S_DMLEAD.[First Login] 
                                THEN V_S_DMLEAD.[Last Login]
                                ELSE V_S_DMLEAD.[First Login] 
                                    END AS [date],
                                'DirectMailOpty' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    V_S_DMLEAD.[Account ID] AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], 
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],V_S_DMLEAD.[QC Approved] AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], V_S_DMLEAD.Status AS [STATUS_CD],
                                    NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM [AnalyticsDB].[dbo].[V_S_DMLEAD]
                            WHERE V_S_DMLEAD.[Last Login] IS NOT NULL OR V_S_DMLEAD.[First Login] IS NOT NULL) 
                        UNION
                            (SELECT NULL AS [contactID],
                                CASE
                                WHEN RPT_JAIME_NEW.StartDate > RPT_JAIME_NEW.EndDate
                                THEN RPT_JAIME_NEW.StartDate
                                ELSE RPT_JAIME_NEW.EndDate
                                    END AS [date],
                                'DirectMailOpty' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    RPT_JAIME_NEW.AccountID AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], 
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],NULL AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], RPT_JAIME_NEW.Status AS [STATUS_CD],
                                    NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM Reporting.dbo.RPT_JAIME_NEW
                            WHERE (RPT_JAIME_NEW.StartDate IS NOT NULL OR RPT_JAIME_NEW.EndDate IS NOT NULL) AND RPT_JAIME_NEW.Type ='Direct Mail') 
                        UNION 
                            (SELECT CSVendorMasterValidData.[Contact ID] AS [contactID],
                                CSVendorMasterValidData.[Lead Generation Date] AS [date],
                                'ContentSyndicationOpty' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    CSVendorMasterValidData.[Siebel Account ID] AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], 
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],CSVendorMasterValidData.[QC Approved] AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD],
                                    NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM Reporting.dbo.CSVendorMasterValidData
                            WHERE CSVendorMasterValidData.[Lead Generation Date] IS NOT NULL) 
                        UNION 
                            (SELECT CSVendorMasterInvalidData.[Contact ID] AS [contactID],
                                CSVendorMasterInvalidData.[Lead Generation Date] AS [date],
                                'ContentSyndicationOpty' AS [event],
                                    NULL AS [hasEmail_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [CUST_STAT_CD] , NULL AS [SUPPRESS_EMAIL_FLG], NULL AS [SUPPRESS_CALL_FLG], 
                                    NULL AS [SUPPRESS_MAIL_FLG],NULL AS [ACTIVE_FLG],
                                    CSVendorMasterInvalidData.[Siebel Account ID] AS [accntID],NULL AS [WORK_PHONE_NUM],
                                    NULL AS [MAIN_PHONE_NUM],NULL AS[JOB_ROLE],NULL AS [JOB_FUNCTION],
                                    NULL AS [hasPhone_FLG],
                                    NULL AS [workPhoneSuperScore], 
                                    NULL AS [HQL_ID],CSVendorMasterInvalidData.[QC Approved] AS [QCApproved],
                                    NULL AS [RESP_TYPE_CD], NULL AS [STATUS_CD],
                                    NULL AS [OptyID],
                                    NULL AS [Disposition],NULL AS [SubDisposition],
                                    NULL AS [AETimezone]
                            FROM Reporting.dbo.CSVendorMasterInvalidData
                            WHERE CSVendorMasterInvalidData.[Lead Generation Date] IS NOT NULL)
                        ) AS [timeseries]
                        WHERE timeseries.date >2007 AND timeseries.date <= GETDATE()
```

Comment: Post the DDL of that `VIEW`. We need a [mre] here. To answer your questions: *"Where is this value coming from?"* One of your tables. *"Why is it trying to convert it to INT?"* because you are comparing it to an `int`. *"How can I sidestep the conversion to avoid the error?"* you don't, you fix the error.

Comment: Your view has a big.  The view needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Larnu - Yes, it is a view. I have added the DDL. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Well, we aren't going to tell you where the problem is there without the DDL of your tables as well (I wasn't expecting so many references, so expected we might be able to spot it), however, either one of your `JOIN`s is comparing a `varchar` to an `int`, or in your `UNION` queries one is returning a `int` and in another a `varchar`. Also, why `UNION`, and not `UNION ALL` here? None of the rows from the dataset can be identical, so the `UNION` appears to just be adding unneeded overhead.

Comment: Also, `WHERE timeseries.date > 2007 AND timeseries.date <= GETDATE()` makes little sense. How can `timeseries.date` be both an `int` and a `datetime`? That clause would likely be parsed as `WHERE timeseries.date > '20190701' AND timeseries.date <= GETDATE()`, but why hind the value of the first date with that `int` value?

Comment: I'm guessing that some of the columns in your unions don't line up right.

Comment: Understood! Let me investigate each and every UNION

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions, they help me find the error